# How to plot the tree of a Light GBM .joblib model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, joblib, lightgbm

I'm very new to Machine Learning! My problem concern a model created with LighGBM. I'm not the creator of this model, so I want to see the tree that this model generates. The model is in the format .joblib, and I want to know as much information as possible of it. On the [LighGBMclassifier Documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.LGBMModel.feature_importances_) i don't find anything that can solve my problem. Thanks to the code below, I only know the number of classes.

```
model = joblib.load("*.joblib.dat")
model.classes_
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1])
```

I want to know the number of rows, the rules and if it's possible, even the plot of the tree. Thank you all!

Comment: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/lightgbm/plotting.html

Comment: you're right! you solve my problem! thank you!

Comment: You may want to look at this:
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/lightgbm/plotting.html

Answer (score 0):

When you can not find something in the LightGBM documentation, look for it at XGBoost documentation. LightGBM documentation has loss of missing features that the framework has actually in it.